# field update in report not getting updated

Tags: reporting, formula, field-update

I have an object, let's call it Object2. 
Object2 has a field called Account which is a lookup. 
Account has a field called customer type. 
Object2 has a formula field which gets populated by Account.Customer_type.

There is a field update that concatenates a few values, including the formula field (Account.Customer_type).

In a report the field update is one of the columns.

Now the issue: if someone updates the customer type on the account, the report still shows the old value.

So I think formula change doesn't trigger the field update. What are the choices to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the sequence of operations when you say "the report still shows the old value"? When you say "field update", are you using Workflow Rules or Process Builder? It's hard to see what the issue is right now.

Comment: `Formulas are only evaluated upon record retrieval` so no DML occurs when the formula is evaluated and hence a WFR will not trigger and ensuing field update will not execute

Comment: @DavidReed field update I am referring to this concept: https://micropyramid.com/blog/field-update-workflow-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report is a red herring here - it has nothing to do with the problem.

Given that you have on Object 2 a field `Customer_Type__c` that is a formula reference to a field on another object (the Account), and you wish to construct another field on Object 2 that concatenates `Customer_Type__c` with other fields, you can't use Workflow Rules. As cropredy noted in a comment, formula fields have no underlying storage and "changes" to their values are not triggerable events.

If you can construct this other field as another formula field, that should be workable. Otherwise, you'll need to write a Process or Apex Trigger on the Account to propagate changes to its field downwards to its child Object 2 records.

Comment: I tried to write the other one as formula but it has a Long Text Area giving me this error: You referenced an unsupported field type called "Long Text Area" using the following field